# HSQLDB object name already exists

Tags: hsqldb

I'm trying to set up an HSQL database for testing, using version 2.2.9, Hibernate 3.6.9, and Spring 3.1.2. We had been using a local postgresql database but are making a switch for testing. I have 40-50 test classes with 200+ tests in total. Each test class works fine if run individually from eclipse. When I use Maven to compile and test everything I have test errors. At some point it seems to be trying to run my init.sql script again and create tables again. I'm getting this as my final cause:

```
Caused by: org.hsqldb.HsqlException: object name already exists: DUAL_ASSET_ASSETID_SEQ
at org.hsqldb.error.Error.error(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.error.Error.error(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.SchemaObjectSet.checkAdd(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.SchemaManager.checkSchemaObjectNotExists(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.StatementSchema.setOrCheckObjectName(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.StatementSchema.getResult(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.StatementSchema.execute(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.Session.executeCompiledStatement(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.Session.executeDirectStatement(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.Session.execute(Unknown Source) ... 52 more
```

I tried using 'IF NOT EXISTS' when creating that table but when I go to create the sequence I'm getting the same error. So it's trying to do more than just that one table, and I can't use 'IF NOT EXISTS' on a CREATE SEQUENCE statement so I'm stuck there.

Is there any reason why my data seems to be loaded again? I'm also occasionally getting this error:

```
2012-10-16 10:55:48,489 [Thread-0] WARN
org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.embedded.HsqlEmbeddedDatabaseConfigurer:shutdown:46 - Could not shutdown embedded database java.sql.SQLException: Database lock acquisition failure: attempt to connect while db opening /closing
at org.hsqldb.jdbc.Util.sqlException(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.jdbc.Util.sqlException(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCConnection.<init>(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCDriver.getConnection(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCDriver.connect(Unknown Source)
at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.SimpleDriverDataSource.getConnectionFromDriver(SimpleDriverDataSource.java:140)
at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.getConnectionFromDriver(AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.java:149)
at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.getConnection(AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.java:119)
at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.embedded.AbstractEmbeddedDatabaseConfigurer.shutdown(AbstractEmbeddedDatabaseConfigurer.java:40)
at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.embedded.EmbeddedDatabaseFactory.shutdownDatabase(EmbeddedDatabaseFactory.java:152)
at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.embedded.EmbeddedDatabaseFactoryBean.destroy(EmbeddedDatabaseFactoryBean.java:65)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DisposableBeanAdapter.destroy(DisposableBeanAdapter.java:211)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.destroyBean(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:498)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.destroySingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:474)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.destroySingletons(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:442)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.destroyBeans(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1071)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.doClose(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1045)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext$1.run(AbstractApplicationContext.java:963) Caused by: org.hsqldb.HsqlException: Database lock acquisition failure: attempt to connect while db opening /closing at org.hsqldb.error.Error.error(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.error.Error.error(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.error.Error.error(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.DatabaseManager.getDatabase(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.DatabaseManager.newSession(Unknown Source) ... 16 more
```

Comment: [This question was cross-posted](http://sourceforge.net/projects/hsqldb/forums/forum/73674/topic/6025433).

Answer (score 2):

The current version of HSQLDB allows CREATE SEQUENCE IF NOT EXISTS statements.

Alternatively for tests, you can simply drop the whole contents of the PUBLIC schema before creating any objects.

```
DROP SCHEMA PUBLIC CASCADE
```